# How to cancel running hangfire job?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, cancellation

This is my codebase. I need to stop running job. I've tried `BackgroundJob.Delete` method and send current jobId but it didn't help.It just deletes the job but not cancelling it. I can run multiple jobs and should be able to stop each of them from `UI`. I tried to use `CancellationToken` but on the `UI` I am using `AJAX` to send request and it takes some milliseconds so I can't even abort this request. Can somebody suggest something please? Thanks.

```
public class JobController : Controller {

    public void InternalLogic(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {

            if (someCondition)
            {

                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    //some logic
                    break;
                }
                
                //continue working
            }
        }

    }

    public void RunLogic(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //some logic
        InternalLogic(id,cancellationToken);
    }

    public void Run(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => this.RunLogic(id, cancellationToken));
    }

}
```

Comment: ```BackgroundJob.Delete``` method will do both – remove a job and cancel it (if you are using cancellation tokens).

Comment: I am sorry but it's not.. I've tried it but any result

Comment: did you tried this solution.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443525/cancel-running-job-scheduled-with-hangfire-io

Comment: Yes. Instead of IJobCancellationToken I am using CancellationToken

Comment: That cancellation token is never used. It's just a placeholder. Hangfire will pass its own cancellation token to allow it to cancel a job when it has to eg, when the application shuts down or when the job status changes. From [the docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html): `any CancellationToken instance can be used, it will be replaced internally just before performing a background job.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how I can cancel Hangfire job without shutting down?

Comment: @ShahinJabbarov the best answer I've found is the one you got in the Github repo. You can't do that through Hangfire, you have to create your own mechanism. Eg, create your own CancellationTokenSource, wrap it in a class so you can register it as a service, and listen to it from your job. To do that you'll have to use a class instead of a lambda and `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MyJobClass>(j=>j.Execute(...))`

Comment: @ShahinJabbarov in other issues [people suggest](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1810) using `BackgrundJob.Delete(id)` where `id` is the actual numeric ID of the job. Getting it isn't that easy though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `BackgrundJob.Delete(id)` doesn't work for me for some reason and that's why I've started to find another solutions..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly, but I believe that the `CancellationToken` you are using is short lived.  The request to start the job executes and completes at which point the `CancellationToken` you are using is useless and will never be cancelled since the request that created it has long since completed successfully and discarded its `CancellationTokenSource`.

If you want to use `CancellationToken`, you will need to create your own `CancellationTokenSource`, keep track of it and cancel the job yourself when you need to cancel it.

Perhaps something similar in concept to:

```
public class JobController : Controller {
    //Not safe, for demonstration purposes only
    private static Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, CancellationTokenSource>();

    private void InternalLogic(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (someCondition)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    //some logic
                    break;
                }
            
                //continue working
            }
        }
    }

    private void RunLogic(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //some logic
        InternalLogic(id,cancellationToken);
    }

    //Client requests that a job is started
    public void Run(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
        var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => this.RunLogic(id, cts.Token));
    }
    
    //Client requests that a job is cancelled.
    public void Cancel(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _dictionary[id].Cancel(); //or perhaps track using jobId?
    }
}
```

This is not a production ready solution - you will want to make sure only the correct user can cancel the correct jobs, and will probably want to find something more elegant and thread safe than a static dictionary.

This solution is not specific to Hangfire - it's just the general idea of how you might signal cancellation of a long running, asynchronous background task.

Comment: I tried but it is not working. I was debugging to make sure `if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)` works but it is not. I am cancelling the token using jobId and it works but doesn't cancel

Comment: I can think of two possible ways that this can happen:

1) You are calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` after `InternalLogic()` has completed.


2) You are calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` for the wrong token (e.g.  for example by overwriting/losing the correct `CancellationTokenSource`)